# User control optimize code

Tags: list, user, user-controls

I have a SharePoint list with data. A user control is there which fetches data from this list and displays it in the SharePoint page.

Now on every page refresh the list is getting hit which is affecting the performance.

Any ideas how to reduce the hits and increase the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can mainly improve performance by:

1. After the first retrieval place the data in HTTP Cache and use it going forward. You can put timeout (when the cache should expire)
2. Make sure you are using CAML queries and retrieving only required fields
3. Apply server side pagination